# Sum of a Prometheus metric over the current day

Tags: prometheus, metrics

I want to have a metric that shows the total incoming bytes on an interface for the day so far.
The closest I can get is having to specify the date in the query, but I was hoping to have something that would work for the current day without changing anything.
What I have right now for a specific day seems to tail off at the end, but maybe that is a property of how the increase function is working? This is what I have so far:

```
(sum(increase(ifen02[2h])) and on () day_of_week() == 2)
```

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: We have gone with the increase over the last 24hrs, instead of the current day : increase(ifen02[24h]). If your display is only if for metrics for the current day then what @kamol said below is good. You don't need the sum() around the increase in case you are wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use this?

```
sum(increase(ifen02[2h]))
```

And from the visualization tools (i.e. Grafana or Prometheus graph) select `last 1 day` or `last 24 hr`, it will show the data of last 1 day relative to current time.

Comment: I have different metrics on a Grafana dashboard, and I wanted only that one to use the current day. The others show the last hour or so. That indeed would work if the metric was displayed on its own dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to query [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) increase for the current day (e.g. since 00:00 of the current day). Prometheus provides the ability to query counter increase over the fixed lookbehind window (aka sliding window) though. For example, the following query returns the counter increase over the last 24 hours:

```
increase(ifen02[24h])
```

If you need counter increase since the beginning of the current day, then the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query can be used:

```
running_sum(
  increase(ifen02)
  if (
    time()+timezone_offset("Europe/Kiev")
    > (now() - now() % (24*3600))
  )
)
```

It is expected that this query is used for building a graph on a time range covering the current day.

This query works in the following way:

1. It calculates the `increase()` for `ifen02` between adjacent points on the graph. VictoriaMetrics automatically converts `increase(ifen02)` into the equivalent of `increase(ifen02[$__interval]))`. See [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) docs and [implicit query conversion docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions).
2. Then it calculates `time()+timezone_offset("Europe/Kiev") > (now() - now() % (24*3600))` . This query returns unix timestamps in `Europe/Kiev` time zone for the current day. It drops all the timestamp for the previous days. See docs for the used functions: [now()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#now), [timezone_offset()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#timezone_offset) and [time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#time).
3. Then the `if` operator leaves the calculated `increase()` values only for the current day starting at 00:00 Europe/Kiev timezone, while dropping all the values for previous days. See docs about `if` operator [here](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#metricsql-features).
4. Then the remaining `increase()` values are summed over the current day with [running_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function. Sometimes it is possible to use [range_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#range_sum) instead of `running_sum`.